# How do I automatically add a new column when a row is added on another tab in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

On the first tab I have 10 rows.

On the second tab I have 10 columns.

If I add a new row to the first tab, I would like it to automatically add another column to the second tab referencing it's data.

---

Tab 1

```
Name    Age    Grade    GPA
Tom     10     5        3.2
Sally   10     6        3.4
Frank   11     6        2.2
```

Tab 2

```
Name    Tom    Sally    Frank
Age     10     10       11
FirstYear 5     4       5    [=Age-Grade]
```

---

So if someone adds "Jim 9     5        2.6" to the first tab, a "Jim" column would be automatically added to Tab 2 with the appropriate fields and formulas.

Comment: That's pretty vague. Just "record a Macro". Developer's tab, Record, add row, switch tabs, add column. Done. Run macro to test. You can even give it a shortcut combination such as "SHIFT + CTRL + R".

Comment: Do you think there is any possible way of doing this without macros? (If no, that at least gives me justification to tell them to build a real program instead of screwing around with this.)

Comment: That's not what you asked for at all. You should describe the data in more detail and give a detailed outcome for what your output should look like. Given data set. And a wish list outcome in detail and worked out manually.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know what you are seeking and have an answer, but if I am wrong, it's because I'm assuming again from the missing information that's not available.

Comment: I added an example that I hope clarifies what I'm looking for.

Comment: Pretty quick adjustment and solution in just a few clicks. Below.

Comment: Ah, you wanted a transposed Table. To columns? I added that for you. If that fits what you're looking for, please don't forget to click the check-mark to accept the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column to your data set to include (=Age-Grad): Table

Data → Get and Transform section → From Table → Choose Columns → Close & Load

[image]

When the "Table" is manipulated, you have to return to Sheet2 in my example to Refresh from the Data Tab.

To transpose the Query:

[image]